# CLOB value too large to insert into DB2 table

Tags: java, oracle, db2, clob, sqlj

I have a java.sql.Clob object which I populate from an Oracle query and then I have to insert this field at DB2 table (also a Clob column). So, at my sqlj class I created a java.sql.Clob type and set the value with the result from Oracle select (also a java.sql.Clob). The length of the Clob I'm trying to insert has about 2,5Mb or dbms_lob.getlength returns 2500012.

When the SQLJ executes, it throws an Exception:

**COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0433N  Value "" is too long.  SQLSTATE=22001**

The DB2 version I'm using is 
Database server        = DB2 OS/390 8.1.0

The Oracle version is 
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit

Do you have any idea why this error is thrown? I was looking for the IBM documentation and it is suppose to use java.sql.Clob object to insert into DB2 clob column...

> "Input parameters for CLOB columns For IN parameters for CLOB columns,
>   or INOUT parameters that are used for input to CLOB columns, you can
>   use one of the following techniques:  Use a java.sql.Clob input
>   variable, which is an exact match for a CLOB column:
>   cstmt.setClob(parmIndex, clobData); ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the size of the CLOB column in the database.
Check this link for maximum clob column size

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0001029.htm